# sudo access to specific folder

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

On mac mavericks, i want to install few files without prompting user for sudo password. (Folder where i am trying to install require root access because it is present at / location). I can do this by modifying "sudoer" file and disable sudo password but this is unsafe and open up security risk. Is there any way i can provide sudo access only a particular folder? So when i try to write to this folder, sudo password prompt is not visible to user.

(All above task are done through command line)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be more appropriate for apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You can't do that directly with sudo.